# C++ array of objects return the same char* for every object

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

```
if (objArr == NULL) {
    objArr = new MyObject[1];
    objArr[0] = obj;
    counter++;
} else {
    MyObject* tmp = objArr;
    objArr= new MyObject[counter+ 1];

    for (int j = 0; j < counter; ++j) {
        objArr[j] = tmp[j];
    }
    objArr[counter] = obj;
    counter++;
    delete[] tmp;
}
```

the object have `char* name` and some other data that stored correctly
when i try to loop the object array it return the other data ok but the `char* name` return the same for every object(the last name that inserted)

```
for (int k = 0; k < playerCount; ++k) {
    objArr[k].printObj();
}
```

printObj(); just cout objArr[k] getObjName()

this is the setter and getter i created:

```
char *MyObject::getObjName() const {
    return this->objName;
}

void MyObject::setObjName(char *name) {
    this->objName = name;
}
```

what im doing wrong?

*i cant use vectors and strings

Comment: The error is most likely in the way you store and manage `objName` in the `MyObject` class. You can get more help by posting the class's code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is common pointer mistake.
If your class/data structure own pointer and allocates it, you should implement own copy constructor that will allocate new memory for char *name.
Now all objects points to one char array, instead of having own char array.

If you don't get what I am talking about, read this at first:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_copy_constructor.htm